# jquery: simple image preloader + onload

Tags: jquery, image, preloading

i'm trying to make a simple image-preloader for just ONE image.
it should load an image and - if finished - fire an event for displaying it.
what's the simplest method to do this?

i only know the pure javascript solution, like document.createElement("img") - but what's the best method using jquery?

what i've got so far (but dunno if it's the optimal way):

```
var img = $("<img src='/images/myPic.jpg'>");
img.bind("load", function(){alert("loaded!")});
```

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand correctly I would write the image in the template or master page or whatever using with a css attribute and then an event in jquery to display it.

```
<img id="preloader" src="/myimg.jpg" style="display:none;" />


$("#some-element").ready(function(){
      $("#preloader").show();
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've never had to do this with jQuery as I either do it manually in JS:

```
var img = new Image();
img.onLoad = function() {alert("Image has been loaded!");};
img.src = "path/to/img.ext";
```

Or, if I'm already using jQuery for the project, I'll just use [Thickbox](http://jquery.com/demo/thickbox/). If you look at its source, it has something similar to the above.

To display it, have a pre-defined div in your source file that is initially set to display: none;, then use JS to set its content to the image and change it to be visible. You can see an example of this at [pcgalore.com](http://www.pcgalore.com/), the rotating quote banner uses it.

Answer (score 0):

I would use jquery's .on() method and attach it to the selector:

```
<img id="preLoader" src="/images/myPic.jpg" alt="My Pic" style="display: none;" />

$('#preLoader').on('load', function () {
    $(this).fadeIn();
});
```